# Green Card Scheme for Denmark Immigration? Financial Requirements?

Tags: residency, denmark

I am eligible for Denmark Green Card but I am confused with the financial requirements written on immigration [official website](http://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-us/coming_to_dk/work/greencard-scheme/financial-requirements.htm) of Denmark.

> To obtain a residence permit under the Greencard scheme, you must document that you can support yourself during your first year in Denmark.
>
> Consequently, when you submit your application you must document that you have at your disposal an amount equivalent to one year's social benefits for single non-providers over the age of 30.
>
> The annual amount is DKK 130,188 (12 x 10,849) for you (the main applicant) (2015 level).

Should I show them that I am earning DKK 10,849/Month from last 12 months or should I show them that I have DKK 130,188 (12 x 10,849) in my bank account at the time of application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rest of the page is pretty clear:

> Documentation can be a bank statement in the main applicant's name. Currency and date of issuance must be clearly stated. The statement must be no more than 30 days old at the time the application is submitted.
>
> Alternatively, you can document your ability to support yourself and any accompanying family members by having a montly income in Denmark which matches the amounts mentioned above.

Past income is not relevant. Unlike requirements for short-stay visas, this is not about your situation in your country of origin (you don't apply for this scheme to return there, at least not immediately) but about making sure you have money available during the first year in Denmark and won't be eligible for social benefits.

Consequently, it really should be money in the bank or, alternatively, a contract showing you will get an income *in Denmark* after you move there.